# processing a dataset too big for memory using Dask + XArray + s3

Tags: dask, python-xarray, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

I would like to find statistics for 30 years worth of gridded data, where the "time" axis must not be chunked. The data is stored on an s3 bucket. I need to save the statistics out as a netcdf.

Processing the data locally, turning the data 1-D, then storing the data as a dataframe on an s3 bucket. Time is saved separately.

```
for year in years:
        time, hs, tp, dp = dl.load_bulk_params(year)
        bathy, lat, lon = dl.load_bathy()

        #flip upside down
        hs = np.flipud(hs).ravel()
        tp = np.flipud(tp).ravel()
        dp = np.flipud(dp).ravel()

        dataframe = pd.DataFrame(
             data = {'hs':hs, 'tp':tp, 'dp':dp}
        )
        time_dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'time':time})
        dataframe.to_parquet(local_path)
       s3.upload(local_path, remote_path)
```

Load the data from the remote:

```
    ddf = dask.dataframe.read_parquet('s3://{}/params/fullspec/out/params_{}_*_*.parquet'))
    time_ddf = dask.dataframe.read_parquet('s3://{}/params/fullspec/out/time_{}_*_*.parquet'))
```

Turn parameter from dask dataframe into dask array, reshape, rechunk and and wrap into xarray, so I can use the xarray functionality to save out as a netcdf:

```
timevec = time_ddf.partitions[:]['time'].values.compute()

    arr = ddf[param].to_dask_array(lengths=True).reshape((len(timevec), len(lat), len(lon))).rechunk((len(timevec), 5,5))

    hs_xr = xr.DataArray(arr, dims = ['time', 'lat', 'lon'], 
                        coords = {'time':timevec, 'lat':lat, 'lon':lon}
                        ).chunk({'time':-1})
```

Calculate necessary statistics using map_partitions and a defined function:

```
def dask_percentile(arr, q, axis = 0):
    if len(arr.chunks[axis]) > 1:
        msg = ('Input array cannot be chunked along the percentile '
            'dimension.')
        raise ValueError(msg)
    return da.array.map_blocks(np.percentile, arr, axis=axis, q=q,
                                drop_axis=axis)

computed_stats_ds = hs_xr.reduce(dask_percentile, dim = 'time', q = 90).compute()
```

Receiving process  "killed"

Should I use a distributed dask cluster (start a client)? I have tried this, also, and I'm using a remote machine so I cannot access the dask dashboard. When I use the client, the memory overflows and the workers are killed. I could reconfigure the dask parameters to allow for higher memory usage.

I thought, though, that the worker would process one chunk at a time. Is the rechunking and reshaping taking too much memory? What am I misunderstanding using Dask?

Another way forward would be to save everything as grids locally then load with xarray using open_mfdataset, but this is not desirable because I'd have to increase the disk space of the remote machine.

Apologies that this is not reproducible; the data is not necessarily available, but if it's needed I can try to make this question reproducible.

Comment: You may wish to cross-post on the pangeo discourse, where people do this kind of workflow routinely.